# Is it possible to dynamically build a String in a culture invariant way?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to write a helper method to dynamically build a string by using the [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) class.

I want to be able to do that in a culture invariant way so that two threads having different cultures get the same result if both call the helper method with the same input.

Unfortunately, many of the `StringBuilder` methods default to the current thread's culture and don't provide a way to control the formatting from outside. An example of this is the [`AppendJoin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendjoin?view=net-6.0#system-text-stringbuilder-appendjoin(system-string-system-object())) method.

Consider the following code:

```
object[] items = { 13.34, new DateTime(2022, 4, 14) };

var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendJoin(" - ", items);
var message = builder.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(message);
```

This code outputs `13.34 - 4/14/2022 12:00:00 AM` if the thread culture is `en-US`. The output becomes `13,34 - 14/04/2022 00:00:00` if the thread culture is `it-IT`.

The core issue is that there is no overload of [`AppendJoin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendjoin?view=net-6.0#system-text-stringbuilder-appendjoin(system-string-system-object())) allowing to provide an instance of [`IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=net-6.0) to control the behavior from outside.

Based on my understanding, the only way to work around this is to use the [`AppendFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat?view=net-6.0) method, which has overloads that take `IFormatProvider`.

Am I missing anything? Is this the right way to solve my use case? Is there a better type in the .NET Core framework to do so?

Comment: I think you're supposed to say culture invariant btw! Culture insensitive has another potential meaning. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0#:~:text=The%20invariant%20culture%20is%20culture,CultureInfo.

Comment: The `StringBuilder.AppendJoin` methods are modeled after `String.Join` and have almost all of the same overloads. Not all types implement a `ToString` overload that accepts an `IFormatProvider` parameter (and when they do, it's not implementing an interface!). How do you propose that it deal with that if it accepted an `IFormatProvider` parameter that it may or may not be able to pass to a `ToString` method (reflection notwithstanding, that is)?

Comment: I would suggest staying clear of `AppendJoin` and `AppendFormat` and simply using the `Append` method overloads. Then you can format each element that goes into the `StringBuilder` individually. If you have special needs, you can build extension methods to do "bulk join" operations to call `Append` repeatedly in a loop. The performance impact of using the culture-sensitive methods when you want invariant output usually isn't worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Besides using AppendFormat, here are a couple of alternative approaches to consider:

1. In your helper method, temporarily change the culture of the current thread to CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, call the StringBuilder methods as usual, and then restore the original culture.
2. Wrap each of the values you pass to StringBuilder in an object that forces the use of the invariant culture:

```
public class InvariantWrapper : IFormattable
{
    private readonly object _value;

    public InvariantWrapper(object value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ToString(null, null);
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return _value switch
        {
            IFormattable formattable => formattable.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            not null => _value.ToString(),
            null => ""
        };
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
builder.AppendJoin(" - ", items.Select(item => new InvariantWrapper(item)));
```

Note: The `switch` expression was introduced in C# 8.0 and the `not null` pattern was introduced in C# 9.0. If you’re using C# 7.x, you can use the following code instead:

```
return _value is IFormattable formattable
    ? formattable.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    : _value != null
        ? _value.ToString()
        : "";
```